# Customization of an app for Enterprise

Tags: ios, ipa, in-house-distribution, ios-enterprise

One of the customers wants my iOS app to be customised and distribute to employees of his client. I found Custom B2B approach best but he is insisting on enterprise distribution and I am sure like me he does not know much about Enterprise deployment and its limitations. I will not be giving the source code but just the customised binary. My questions :

a. Is it possible to build an ipa and sign it with the enterprise certificate and deliver it ?

b. Will there be lot of support required from my side on enterprise distribution and device management ?

c. Is it possible to limit the number of licences of app while distributing it on enterprise network ? If yes, what is the best way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple supports three app deployment methods.

B2C - aka - the normal app store

B2B - this looks and acts like the normal app store but the app is not visible to the general public.
The only way to get an app to someone is via invitation using a redemption code.  This looks to the user like a hybrid of a gift card redemption and a link to an app in the app store.
For this you "purchase" (they can be free) a set of redemption codes from Apple.  They send them to you in a spreadsheet.  You are then responsible for distributing the codes and tracking which have been used.  Apple will send a report of those that were successfully redeemed.
This method can only be used if the app meets Apples criteria for B2B.  If they feel it is something that could be on the general app store that is where they expect it to be.  The sticking points are really around functionality that can only be used by your business partners, no redeeming public value.
This is also a valuable in ensuring that you don't have an app that gets poor reviews by people that can't use it because it is only useful to your partners.

B2A - aka Enterprise Deployment.  This is a special and seperate development account that allows you to host an internal app store and package your own applications for in house deployment.  Apple will only allow companies that meet certain requirements to have this type of account.  There are strict rules around the deployment as well.  Apps may only be distributed to employee devices and are not allowed to be distributed to non employees/customers/business partners.